# Problem with mounting docker and postgres on golang

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I am trying to mount a container in docker with postgres sql, I tried to remove the password to see if it could start the container but it still keeps throwing me the following error:

```
Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

My docker file is structured like this

```
FROM postgres:15.1
COPY up.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
CMD ["postgres"]
```

I have tried launching the command `docker run -p 54321:5432 db POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` in the console.

Comment: Are you running a postgres docker container?

Comment: If you are building your docker container, you should pass the env variables like dbname, dbpass and the like.

Comment: PORT=:5050
JWT_SECRET=secret
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:54321/postgres?
sslmode=disable

Esta es la estructura de mi .env

Comment: You can pass environment variables to your containers with the -e flag.

An example from a startup script:

sudo docker run -d -t -i -e REDIS_NAMESPACE='staging' \ 
-e POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD='foo' \
-e POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_USER='bar' \
-e POSTGRES_ENV_DB_NAME='mysite_staging' \
-e POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR='docker-db-1.hidden.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' \
-e SITE_URL='staging.mysite.com' \
-p 80:80 \
--link redis:redis \  
--name container_name dockerhub_id/image_name

Comment: Well, I have used the variable "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" and still, it gives me problems

Comment: `"-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".` Did you pass the env  variables like dbuser, dbpass, dbname, and the like?

Comment: docker run --name postgresql -e POSTGRES_USER=myusername -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword -p 5432:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres

Comment: I have done what you indicate, and everything is fine, it does not generate an error, but it does not start the server, and the console returns a kind of token

Comment: What's the console output? sudo docker run -d -t -i -e REDIS_NAMESPACE='staging' \ -e POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD='foo' \ -e POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_USER='bar' \ -e POSTGRES_ENV_DB_NAME='mysite_staging' \ -e POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR='docker-db-1.hidden.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' \ -e SITE_URL='staging.mysite.com' \ -p 80:80 \ --link redis:redis \ --name container_name dockerhub_id/image_name Did you use all these? These are placeholders

Comment: d491287c7ce0174e6d3ffeed78995e8ef90507d0c3a23418e68fb4134363f9b

Comment: What command did you run exactly?

Comment: docker run --name postgresql -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -p 54321:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d testdb

Comment: Are these the correct creds? Don't try to write the creds here, am just asking if you have used the correct values. `54321`, are you connecting to the port? And `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, `testdb` are placeholders.